# Getting started with Microsoft Outlook API in an Enterprise setting

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm interested in creating a simple site that lists the conference rooms where I work and shows their availability and info on who booked a room and for how long.  It's just a read-only app for ease of getting info on the fly through the mobile browser.  I'm basically trying to figure out where to begin with this.

I work at a very large enterprise agency and it looks like we have our own exchange server.  I don't know much else about it. I'm a developer but I don't know anything about Microsoft Server Ecosystem.

I just want to know:

Am I ready to just dive in and start using some Microsoft API or do I need to get some specific information from my IT dept about some service pack that needs to be installed or some api permission that needs to be activated?

If I do need talk to my IT dept, what should I be asking them specifically?

I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a courtesy (and especially in large environments) you should talk to the IT department and let them know what your going to do just from a security point of view as the traffic your app might start to generate could be different enough that they will come and see you (which is generally not a good thing).

But what you want to ask them is what version of Exchange they are running, is Exchange Web Service available (it will generally be) and what is the EWS endpoint (you can work this out yourself using an app like the EWSEditor). If you are using Office365 or they have a hybrid setup. Have they used RoomLists for the MeetingRooms you want to access (this will make it easy for a application to dynamically find them). Once you have that information you can then make a choice about API's eg if you using Office365 use the new REST api's dev.outlook.com or if it OnPrem Exchange 2010,13,16 look at using EWS. Discovery of Meeting rooms can be issue if you want this to be dynamic (eg detects new rooms as they are added) if RoomList's haven't been used, for this you may need to look at another API like using LDAP.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I needed.  I will definitely talk to them first.  I'm not sure if this is normal but the way my company handles Conference rooms is that each conf room is a "user" that has its own email and you book a room by inviting that user to your meeting.  And you can see that conference room's availability by looking at their schedule like you would any other person in the company.   Is that normal?  I feel like Outlook has better ways of handling conference rooms

Comment: Outlook uses EWS to do what your talking about via the GetUserAvailiblity operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564001(v=exchg.150).aspx which allows you to specify multiple addresses and compare the time against each other. It also has the suggest meeting time feature you see in outlook https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532560(v=exchg.80).aspx. The other option is you just query the Meeting Room Calendar directly (like you would if you open that folder in Outlook) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx